# How do I handle a failed post operation using Giraffe?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I handle a failed post operation using Giraffe?

What's the recommended practice for a failed post operation using Giraffe?

```
let private registrationHandler = 
    fun(context: HttpContext) -> 
        async {
            let! data = context.BindJson<RegistrationRequest>()
            let response = register data |> function
                                         | Success profile -> profile
                                         | Failure         -> ???
            return! json response context 
        }
```

Specifically, if the server fails to write data to some database, what should I return to the client (that will compile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handler has to return something, but it doesn't always have to be the same serialized object. I've only had a quick glance at Giraffe, but using similar approach from Suave with Giraffe's examples here: https://github.com/dustinmoris/Giraffe#setstatuscode, I would do something like this:

```
type ErrorResponse = { message: string; ... }

let private registrationHandler = 
    fun(context: HttpContext) -> 
        async {
            let! data = context.BindJson<RegistrationRequest>()
            match register data with
            | Success profile ->
                return! json profile context
            | Failure ->
                let response = { message = "registration failed"; ... }
                return! (setStatusCode 500 >=> json response) context
        }
```